# How can I add data to a Google Places API result?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places

I'm using Google Places API along with Google Maps API to locate a place on a map. I have this working fine and have a marker dropping on the specific places I'm looking for, like this:

[image: Google Place marker on Google Map]

My question, when I click/touch this marker, how can I have a button to allow a user to add information to the place this marker is?

For example, if this marker was a restaurant, how could I have an 'Add' button, to allow the user to 'Add a review' to this restaurant? So beside "Location A" in the below image, there would be the name of the location and an "Add" button?

[image: Displaying location information]

I know how to store/retrieve data from a db, that's fine, but literally just getting the add button to display?

AND if there is data already added for this Place, how can I display it on the Places tag for another user to see? i.e., if there has already been a Review of a place, how can I see in the title "Location A. Review = ..."

Thanks in advance,
Any parts that are unclear just let me know.